# Font Awesome 4.7 Icons Not Showing in Django S3 Project

Tags: django, amazon-s3, font-awesome

Font Awesome 4.7 icons are showing squares in my Django project when using Amazon S3.

**Question I'm trying to answer is: Why is my CSS working but not my Font Awesome icons?**

---

**Locally, when DEBUG = True**

[image: Debug is True]

**The Font Awesome Icons work:**

[image: Icons work]

**When I set DEBUG = False:**

[image: debug is false]

**My settings.py uses Amazon S3 bucket settings:**

```
if DEBUG:
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static_cdn')
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
    ]

    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'media_cdn')
else:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']

    AWS_FILE_EXPIRE = 200
    AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True
    AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = True

    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'helloworld.storage_utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'helloworld.storage_utils.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'

    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME']
    S3DIRECT_REGION = 'us-west-2'
    S3_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
    MEDIA_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
    MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_URL
    STATIC_URL = S3_URL + 'static/'
    ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'

    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
    ]

    import datetime

    two_months = datetime.timedelta(days=61)
    date_two_months_later = datetime.date.today() + two_months
    expires = date_two_months_later.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y 20:00:00 GMT")

    AWS_HEADERS = {
        'Expires': expires,
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=%d' % (int(two_months.total_seconds()),),
    }
```

**Font Awesome 4.7 icons don't work (shows squares):**

[image: Font awesome icons don't work]

**In my S3 bucket, I have my CSS directory setup the same as locally:**

[image: CSS directory on S3]

**I also have the fonts directory setup (same as locally)**

[image: fonts directory on S3]

**When referencing the files in my templates, I'm using:**

```
<!-- Font awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'helloworld/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}">
```

**The rendered HTML on the rendered page is**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://helloworldbucket939384.s3.amazonaws.com/static/helloworld/css/font-awesome.min.css?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIASGAGAKANCPZIIB4B&amp;Signature=47QKoudsrtfjFUm8UAIA8sjg1Ck%3D&amp;Expires=1576786765">
```

Comment: Static files are *not* served by Django when `DEBUG` is set to `False`. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: Why does my CSS work then but not my icons when DEBUG is set to `False`?

Comment: I just set `DEBUG = False`, added a javascript `alert("Hey");` to "js" folder, ran collectstatic to upload to the bucket, and the alert is firing when Debug is False - meaning static files are serving locally from S3 (not Django).

Comment: Did you ever find the solution? Having the same problem rn

Comment: @RicardoVilaça I did figure it out but it was a long time ago. I just looked through my solution but I can't figure out what I did to solve it. If I do, I'll post.

Answer (score 2):

I simply added this line under all my JS imports and it works for me:

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e81d17d39f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had identical issue. In my case I..;

- entered the running Docker container
- installed nano via: *apk add nano*
- edited base.html of jazzmin with the above line

Before I had tried to edit "fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" without success.

Edit*

It turned out that my "Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)" didn't have necessary methods.

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "HEAD",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the s3 bucket
2. Switch to the Permission Tab
   [Permission Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRb7c.png)

3. Edit Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) as follows

> ```
> [
>     {
>         "AllowedHeaders": [
>             "*"
>         ],
>         "AllowedMethods": [
>             "GET"
>         ],
>         "AllowedOrigins": [
>             "http://your-domain.com"
>         ],
>         "ExposeHeaders": []
>     }
> ]
> ```

This solved my issue. :)